# jQuery UI Dialog Buttons won't hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Somehow this code doesn't work properly.
All Buttons are shown, only the "Generate" Button hides after the sucessful link generation. On the same site I have another dialog, implement the same way, which is working fine.

```js
$("#guest-link-dialog").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  resizable: false,
  height: 300,
  width: 510,
  modal: true,
  draggable: false,
  closeOnEscape: false,
  open: function() {
    $("#closeButton").hide();
  },
  buttons: [{
    id: 'generateButton',
    text: 'Generieren',
    click: function() {

      $('#generatedlink').html('<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/images/icons/32x32/loading.gif" alt="loading" style="padding-left:215px;padding-top:40px;" />');

      $.getJSON('<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/index.php?r=ajax/guestlink&fileid=' + $(this).data('fileid') + '&count=' + $('#inputcount').val())
        .done(function(json) {
          if (json.status == "SUCESS") {
            $('#generatedlink').html('<a href="' + json.url + '" >' + json.url + '</a>');

            $('#generateButton').hide();
            $('#cancelButton').hide();
            $('#closeButton').show();
          } else if (json.status == "ERROR") {
            $("#message").css('color', 'red');
          }

          $("#message").text(json.message);
        })
        .fail(function(json) {
          $("#message").css('color', 'red');
          $("#message").text('Fehler');
        });
    }
  }, {
    id: 'closeButton',
    text: 'Schliessen',
    click: function() {
      $(this).dialog('close');
    }
  }, {
    id: 'cancelButton',
    text: 'Abbrechen',
    click: function() {
      $(this).dialog("close");
    }
  }],
  close: function() {
    $("#message").css('color', '');

    $('#generatedlink').html('');

    $('#generateButton').show();
    $('#cancelButton').show();
    $('#closeButton').hide();
  }
});
```

**Edit:**

```html
<div id="guest-link-dialog" title="Gast Link erstellen">      
 <form>
  <fieldset style="border:1;">
   <label for="count">Anzahl m&ouml;gliche Downloads</label>
   <input type="text" name="count" id="inputcount" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" size="1" value="1" maxlength="1" />
  </fieldset>
 </form>
 <div id="generatedlink" style="width:100%"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you also post your HTML?

Comment: Your posted HTML does not contain any of the buttons, can you update it to show how the buttons are created?

Comment: The Buttons  come from jQuery UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, the Button IDs were already used by the other Dialog. 
Giving them other IDs solves the problem.